# "Plusieurs" tout seul peut-il être féminin s'il désigne un groupe de femme. Ex: "Plusieurs ont été tuées dans cet accident"?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, adjectifs, orthographe, accord

Puisque les adverbes de quantités peuvent être pluriel masculin ou pluriel féminin, je me demande si c'est le même cas pour le mot "plusieurs", même si ce n'est pas un adverbe mais un adjectif.

Comment: Aucune recherche à indiquer?

Comment: Dans *Plusieurs ont été tuées dans cet accident*, *plusieurs* est un pronom mis pour *des femmes du groupe*. L'accord est donc correct.

Comment: lusieurs
 

Plusieurs est un déterminant ou un pronom indéfini. **Pluriel et invariable, il prend toujours un s final**.  Il s’emploie aussi bien avec des noms masculins que féminins. http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2886

Answer (score 1):

***Plusieurs*** est un pronom indéfini dans la phrase de la question, bien qu'il puisse représenter un groupe féminin, il reste invariable.

Il n'empêche qu'on trouve relativement facilement sa version au féminin, y compris dans des ouvrages imprimés ayant pourtant bénéficié de relectures, ce qui prouve que cette orthographe ne surprend pas toujours.

En voici un exemple tiré d'un livre d'enseignement de la langue française :

[image]

*Französisch lernen mit Witzen*, 1990.

Ici comme titre en 1984, mais le féminin y est intentionnel :

[image]

> LC — En effet, dans *Plusieures*, ajouter un « e » féminin à un pronom indéfini et pluriel, c’était entreprendre un travail acharné contre cette langue où les femmes sont soumises à des détournements de sens.